# How to find how many iframe present in source code -Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

There is a span dropdown and inside there are 3 more dropdowns. I need to first select "home" and then "task tracking" and the option in that drop down.

I have seen the `iframe` present in the source code and I am not able to find and put the solution in my python code.

[example HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbxlx.png)

Both `find_element_by_css_selector` and `find_element_by_xpath` are giving the error

```
Errors- AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'tagName'
```

This is my code:

```
size = self.driver.find_element(By.tagName("iframe"))
print(size)
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TitleCaret').click() #Drop down

sleep(10)
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#chrome-sidebar > div > div.chrome-links > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a').click()    #Select Director from drop down

#self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LoanBar"]/span[2]/button').click()

size = self.driver.find_element(By.tagName("iframe"))
print(size)
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.ID, self.iframe_id))
sleep(10)
self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.iframe_id)

#self.driver.switch_to.frame('ifr_APP')
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#LoanBar > span.dropdown > button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium in Python has `By.TAG_NAME` attribute.
`By.tagName` is Selenium Java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

it's `self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"iframe")`